# How to create a dynamic menu in Visual C++ Windows Form Application?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, menu, c++-cli

I am building a C++ windows form application in Visual Studio 2015.
I have a settings menu that has a Save and a Load sub item.
I would like to add sub items to the Load on start up, after reading the settings from a file so, that if the user clicks on the item, the actual settings are loaded.

The settings are successfully read into an array of a `ref class` defined for these settings. But for some reason the menu items are not created and added.
The way i am trying is that in the `Load` event of the `Form` I run a `readSettings()` function that reads from the file and fills the settings to the array, and after filling it in the array, creates a `ToolStripMenuItem`, and set the name, size, and text for it, then add it to the `loadToolStripMenuItem` which is my load menu.

The code is:

```
            //Then add an Item to Load Menu
            ToolStripMenuItem^ menuItem;
            menuItem->Name = name + "LoadMenuSubItem";
            menuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 24);
            menuItem->Text = name;
            //menuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::loadSettings);
            loadToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->AddRange(
                gcnew array<ToolStripMenuItem^>(1) {menuItem});
```

I commented out the line when i am trying to add event handler, because i have no idea how to make it work...
The second argument of EventHandler should be EventArgs corresponding to the documentation. But as far as i could see in the code that Visual Studio generated, it is the name of the actual event handler function, not arguments. In my case it is necessary to pass an argument to the loadSettings function. The `name` variable should be this argument.

(The `loadSettings(String^ name)` function is also tested, and works correctly).
And I also cannnot create an event handler function manually, because the number of the saved settings is not limited...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You cannot write a Windows Forms application using C++. Retagged using [tag:c++-cli].

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, and thanks for retagging :)

Comment: Okay...I found out that I made a simple mistake, that I didn't give a value to menuItem, so I was trying to work with a `nullptr` and the exception handlig of the text file reading caught the exception, so i didn't get an error mesage. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
So correctly: `ToolStripMenuItem^ menuItem = gcnew ToolStripMenuItem();` . But I still have no idea how to pass an argument in the event handler... May anyone have any ideas about that?